# informatica code has generated 476 Gigs of session logs in Dev

Tags: data-warehouse, informatica, informatica-powercenter

My informatica code has generated 476 gigs of session logs in Dev.

Can some one explain how to reduce these logs, any settings in session level.

what are the checks I need to do in Session level and coding level.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is usually due to logging levels set on the session

Edit the session. Select config object tab there is override tracing which should be set to Normal not verbose initialisation or verbose data. Same for the tracing level on each of your transformations in the mapping tab of the session.

You don't debug by generating millions of lines of logfile and trawling through all of them, you find ways to reduce the load such as running fewer records otherwise this is performance test where logging level should not be set above normal

Answer (score 0):

You have to first check what being logged. One common scenario I have seen is the session log recording all rejected data, which causes the session log to be huge. If that is the case, and if you are expecting data to be rejected you can switch off record level logging in session properties.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply but incase if we switch off we will not be able to track whether the records loaded or not. Please let me know if there is any another work around to decrease session logs.

Answer (score 0):

Set the session property `Stop on Error` to 1. Thus if there is an error in the session and records are being rejected you can see that upfront, otherwise session will run probably long time and you will see there are errors in the processing.
Also make sure tracing is set to Normal.